# How to estimate ripple current for PWM loads?

Tags: capacitance, ripple-current

I'm buying some caps for a PCB which I'm designing, and I'm not quite sure how to estimate the ripple current they need to be.

This PCB is intended to switch about ~15A from 12V to 24V at ~100kHz.

The PSU for it is a switching aluminum box, usually rated at 30A. (The PSU already has some huge caps in it and even if I run the PCB without caps everything runs ok).

In all other instances of this design I've just put 2~8 220uF 35V caps in parallel at the board and never had any problems, I'd just like to have a second opinion.

Comment: Opinion on what?

Comment: Estimating how much ripple current should the caps be rated for. I have no idea if 1Amp total is ok or if I should be using higher rated caps.

Comment: I have some idea on how to find out ripple current for rectifier caps but not for DC banks.

Comment: You can calculate the ripple current if you know the Voltage waveform the caps will be exposed to. You can use I = C dV/dt and integrate it over some range. The real current will be somewhat less due to series resistances.

Comment: If you have all the stuff handy, you can just measure it in the lab. If you have a current probe, use that. If not, capture the ripple voltage waveform on the scope (AC coupled). Make sure the supply has a dummy load on it that is around the same as the real load.

Comment: Ok I'll measure it. I just thought there could be some kind of rule of thumb or ballpark to begin with.

Comment: Well, if the voltage ripple is a sine wave (more or less) you could just use the impedance formula for a capacitor to calculate the  magnitude of the current. But there is just not enough information to figure it out from what you have posted.

Comment: If you know your 12 to 24 SMPS frequency and the inductance and ballpark the duty cycle at 50% if its continuos then ripple current drops out  easily.

Comment: What do you mean by "drop out"?